# Play 1.4.3 -- UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer

Tags: playframework, java-8

**Framework version:** 1.4.3
**Platform**: Java 1.8.0_74, Ubuntu 16.04, 64-bit

**Details:**
Trying to upgrade play version from 1.2.7 to 1.4.3. Had to upgrade some modules/libs for 1.4.3.

Starting the app through play run, resulting in following exception:

```
@722hc68nl
Error during the 500 response generation

Oops: UnexpectedException
Unexpected error : While applying play.CorePlugin@1de5f259 on controllers.Application, caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Application

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@1de5f259 on controllers.Application
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:656)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:242)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:165)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:166)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:425)
    at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAssignableClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:466)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.endTag(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:363)
    at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.generate(TemplateCompiler.java:93)
    at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:15)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplateCompiler.compile(GroovyTemplateCompiler.java:40)
    at play.templates.TemplateCompiler.compile(TemplateCompiler.java:28)
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:81)
    at play.templates.TemplateLoader.load(TemplateLoader.java:176)
    at play.server.PlayHandler.serve500(PlayHandler.java:836)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on controllers.Application
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:311)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:651)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: renderDelegate ()V in controllers.Application: conflict: *top* and java.lang.Object
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:777)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
    at play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer.java:251)
    at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:306)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: renderDelegate ()V in controllers.Application: conflict: *top* and java.lang.Object
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:111)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:456)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMapIf6(MethodInfo.java:438)
    at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:768)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: conflict: *top* and java.lang.Object
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$BasicType.setType(TypeData.java:156)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.checkParamTypes(Tracer.java:930)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doInvokeMethod(Tracer.java:801)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode148_201(Tracer.java:595)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doOpcode(Tracer.java:81)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:187)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.traceException(MapMaker.java:221)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:182)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:199)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:164)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:108)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: Had the same thing happen to me. Still haven't found a solution. Did you?

Comment: Problem seems to be related to javassist jar. I have tried 2 solutions, I am noting them as an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to javassist jars.

**Solution - 1:**
Solution suggested in play issues list is to exclude javassist jar in dependencies.yml.

```
require:
    - play: exclude:
       - org.javassist -> javassist *
```

Link: [Issue# 1434](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1434-unexpectedexception-while-applying-class-playclassloadingenhancerslocalvariablesnamesenhancer-new-version)

*However, this did not solve the problem in my case.*

**Solution-2: (*More of a work around*)**
One of the forum suggested this problem is related to code length of the method (in my case `renderDelegate()` ). I have refactored the method to reduce number of lines. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your local variables are initialized. For objects, you must use **null** to initialize it even if it's not semantically necessary.

```
java.io.BufferedWriter bw = null;
```